# Python Parsing XML to DataFrame with absent Elements

Tags: python, xml, dataframe, xml-parsing

I would like to parse an xml file, but some elements for some employees are absent. In the example below, not all employees have data on employment.

This is an example file:

```
<Employees
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="https://www.portalvs.sk/regzam/employees.xsd"
    generated="2020-09-14">
    <Employee Id="87912190">
    <GivenName>John</GivenName>
    <FamilyName>Test1</FamilyName>
    </Employee>
    <Employee Id="40286072">
    <GivenName>Josh</GivenName>
    <FamilyName>Test2</FamilyName>
    </Employee>
    <Employee Id="79273304">
    <GivenName>Mark</GivenName>
    <FamilyName>Test3</FamilyName>
    </Employee>
    <Employee Id="62028843">
    <GivenName>Cath</GivenName>
    <FamilyName>Test4</FamilyName>
    <Employment>
        <Workplace Code="995000000">
        <University Code="995000000">UniversityTest</University>
        </Workplace>
        <BeginDate>2013-11-01</BeginDate>
    </Employment>
    </Employee>
    <Employee Id="24030368">
    <GivenName>Becky</GivenName>
    <FamilyName>Test5</FamilyName>
    <Employment>
        <Workplace Code="998000000">
        <University Code="998000000">UniversityTest2</University>
        </Workplace>
        <BeginDate>2008-09-01</BeginDate>
    </Employment>
    </Employee>
</Employees>
```

I would like to create a DataFrame with employee_id, employee_first_name, employee_last_name, university_code and begin_date. For those employees with no data on employment, I would like the university values to be missing.

```
employee_id employee_first_name employee_last_name university_code begin_date
87912190    John                Test1              NaN             NaN
40286072    Josh                Test2              NaN             NaN
79273304    Mark                Test3              NaN             NaN
62028843    Cath                Test4              995000000       2013-11-01
24030368    Becky               Test5              998000000       2008-09-01
```

Would appreciate your help as I am relatively new with Python and completely new to xml parsing.

Comment: Welcome @samuelsson91, please include what you have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `beautifulsoup` for parsing the XML. Other options would be `lxml` for example.

If `txt` contains your XML snippet, then this code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


soup = BeautifulSoup(txt, 'html.parser')

all_data = []
for e in soup.select('employee'):
    all_data.append({
        'employee_id': e['id'],
        'employee_first_name': e.givenname.text,
        'employee_last_name': e.familyname.text,
        'university_code': e.university['code'] if e.university else None,
        'begin_date': e.begindate.text if e.begindate else None
    })

df = pd.DataFrame(all_data)
print(df)
```

creates this dataframe:

```
  employee_id employee_first_name employee_last_name university_code  begin_date
0    87912190                John              Test1            None        None
1    40286072                Josh              Test2            None        None
2    79273304                Mark              Test3            None        None
3    62028843                Cath              Test4       995000000  2013-11-01
4    24030368               Becky              Test5       998000000  2008-09-01
```